# I need to tell laravel 10 that the public folder will now be public_html. Would?

Tags: laravel-10

I have an application created with Laravel 10. However, when uploading it to a shared server, there is a difference in the names of the public folder. This would be bad because I need to use github to synchronize my files, and when pointing github in hostinger to the rais "/" folder there is the public_html folder that receives all public files. However, these public files are in a folder called public in the root directory. Would you like to: Change the entire folder structure from public to public_html in Laravel?
In this case it would be the best solution. or on the server do an htaccess inside the public_html folder redirecting to the project's public folder one level higher?

I tried several solutions, but as I'm new. I don't have the ability to solve this problem